# Java 8 Streams group by function, setting nested object's variable as key and parent object as value

Tags: java, collections, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I assume my question is somewhat clear from the title.

I have two classes : `parent A and child B.`
and want to have return like `Map<Integer,A>` where `key is a field from` `child B`.
I have `List<A> aList` extracted from database.
Class Definitions:

```
public class B {
    Integer id;
    String some;
    String some2;
}

public class A {
    Integer id;
    B someB;
    String name;
}
```

I was trying like `aList.streams.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A::getSomeB))` but this is not what I want.
There is only one to one relationship between parent and child so I don't need `Map<Integer,List<A>> as the result`

I can do this by looping the `aList` but if there is a built in Java 8 function, I would like to use it.

Comment: I don't follow your question, but I'm left wondering whether this operation should have been performed in the database, and not in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking out for `Collectors.toMap` to collect the map of `B.id` and `A` as the object

```
Map<Integer, A> result = aList.stream().collect(
              Collectors.toMap(a -> a.getSomeB().getId(), Function.identity());
```

Comment: @HadiJ `Map<Integer,A>` would be the return type of the above

Comment: @HadiJ I will try it.

Comment: You should not specify a merge function like `(a1, b) -> b` when the OP says that there should be a one to one relationship between parent and child, as throwing an exception when this assertion does not hold, is the right way to deal with that.

Comment: @Holger Sure, I was expecting someone to definitely point that out.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need streams for that, in such a trivial case:

```
Map<Integer, A> map = new HasMap<>();
aList.forEach(x -> map.merge(x.getSomeB().getId(), x, (oldV, newV) -> throw new AssertionError("must never happen"));
```